# Pyspark (spark 1.6.x) ImportError: cannot import name Py4JJavaError

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Apache-Spark (pyspark) and everything works fine. Now, I am trying to load a data that may or may not exist. So, I am trying to catch the Py4JJavaError and am trying to import it as follows:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import Py4JJavaError
ImportError: cannot import name Py4JJavaError
```

When I unzip this file:
    /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.2/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip

And inspect this file:
    java_gateway.py

I find no `Py4JJavaError`.

What am I doing wrong? Any other place / path I should be using instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `from py4j.protocol import Py4JJavaError`.